# Exporting To Excel from Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel

In my application, the user is able to export a table to excel.

For the past few weeks this has been working perfectly, but now when the table is exported.. excel opens up but nothing happens.. it stays blank like so:

[image]

Now, when the user clicks the button to export to excel a pop up appears asking to open or save.. and to get around this issue we can save the document and then open it, and then it works.  But a couple of weeks ago, that remedy was not needed.

This is what excel looked like a couple of weeks ago when the user exported to excel.

[image]

Then once the user hits 'yes' then the table appears.. but now this only appears after we first save the spreadsheet and then open it, not if we open directly from application.

The end of my method to export to excel looks like this:

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=DailySummaryExport.xls");
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
Response.Charset = "";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
gv.RenderControl(htw);
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

So my question is how do I get this to open up properly without having to save the document first?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this Microsoft link

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsofficedeveloper/2008/05/08/office-2007-file-format-mime-types-for-http-content-streaming-2/

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="DailySummaryExport.xls"');
```

Comment: Where does that go?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  This problem was due to my excel trust center settings.

I had to uncheck specific boxes to allow excel to trust the webpage that is sending it the spreadsheet.